# How to configure Active Directory for SonarQube 5.6.3 with LDAP 2.0 plugin?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube

I'm struggling with configuring the [LDAP 2.0 plugin for Sonarqube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) 5.6.3 LTS for Active Directory. I read all the plugin docs and got this for our environment:

```
# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=false
sonar.forceAuthentication=true
ldap.url=ldap://ad1.prod:1389
ldap.bindDn=CN=myUser,OU=Service-Accounts,DC=ad1,DC=prod
ldap.bindPassword=myPassword

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=DC=ad1,DC=prod
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=displayName
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

and when I start Sonarqube I get:

```
INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=DC=ad1,DC=prod, request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0})), realNameAttribute=displayName, emailAttribute=mail}
INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Groups will not be synchronized, because property 'ldap.group.baseDn' is empty.
INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection: FAIL
ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open LDAP connection
    at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.testConnection
```

I've tried tweaking the configuration a bit but no luck. Anything stand out to anyone who's more familiar with this?

Comment: If you're using an Active Directory server then you might want to have a look at the `Example for Active Directory Server` in the [LDAP Plugin documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) (notably for `ldap.user.request`). And SonarQube aside, you could first validate all these parameters with dedicated tools like `ldapsearch`. Then update your question with what you've tried, findings, and debug logs.

Comment: There is no Example for Active Directory in the LDAP Plug documentation link you provided (same docs I was using). I'm not an LDAP guy and all our AD folks are off in training. I was hoping someone could at least tell me whether or not my configuration as posted makes basic sense. I think the docs leave a lot to be desire, and a UI to configure LDAP/AD would be much preferable. I opened an enhancement request for this.

Comment: @Nicolas - Yup. Example for Active Directory - you meant the column on the right that was off my screen. I thought you were talking about a section or topic. My bad.

Comment: Could you please tell me where should go this configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base problem was wrong LDAP port:

```
ldap.url=ldap://ad1.prod:1389
```

should be

```
ldap.url=ldap://ad1.prod:389
```

I never bothered to question the 1389 port even though that's not the default LDAP port since I'd copy/pasted from another, working app. I guess I fat-fingered something in the process.

Also, this:

```
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
```

had to be this:

```
ldap.user.request=(sAMAccountName={0})
```

to actually enable searching AD. This is an implementation-specific thing.

Answer (score 7):

A more efficient search for AD would be something like:

```
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
```

Comment: This is the better answer.